# i want to use broadcastreceiver to start an activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

i am running my app on android version 2.2.1 and i am using broadcastreceiver to to start an activity as soon as my screen unlocks.this this is not happening...can anyone help me
here is my code

```
import com.example.app.MainActivity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;

public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    Activity ac = new Activity();@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            //Toast.makeText(context, "action received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClass(context, MainActivity.class);
            ac.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
       <receiver android:name="ScreenReceiver">
         <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"/>
               </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should NEVER instantiate `Activity` with `new`. Here is correction of how you should have done it. Just use the method parameter `context`.

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```